# How can I make it so when an Option is chosen on OptionMenu and a button is pressed then for something to happen for that specific option

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm wanting to have it so when an option is pressed in my option menu and is selected for this case being States. I want my calculate functions to work for that state in particular and not other states. All calculate functions have a formula to calculate tax and payroll for each state. Please help me assign values to these options upon selection!

````
import tkinter as tk

#WINDOW PROPERTIES
GUI = tk.Tk()
GUI.title("Payroll Calculator")
#GUI.minsize('305','110')
#GUI.maxsize('305','110')

States = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']

def saying():
    ("Total weeks pay: ")
hoursWorked = tk.StringVar()
payRate = tk.StringVar()
```

AL2 = tk.StringVar(GUI)
AZ2 = tk.StringVar(GUI)
AK2 = tk.StringVar(GUI)

#BUTTON

#CALCULATED ALABAMA
def calculateAL():
    salaryAL = (ALTax())
    resultsAL = tk.Label(GUI, text = "Total Pay: $" + "%.2f" % salaryAL).grid(row=5, column=1)
def ALTax():
    global hoursWorked, payRate
    return (float(hoursWorked.get()) * float(payRate.get())) - (float(payRate.get()) * AL)
AL2.trace("w", ALTax)
#CALCULATED ARIZONA
def calculateAZ():
    salaryAZ = (AZTax())
    resultsAZ = tk.Label(GUI, text = "Total Pay: $" + "%.2f" % salaryAZ).grid(row=5, column=1)
def AZTax():
    global hoursWorked, payRate
    return (float(hoursWorked.get()) * float(payRate.get())) - (float(payRate.get()) * AZ)
AZ2.trace("w", AZTax)
#CALCULATED ALASKA
def calculateAK():
    salaryAK = (AKTax())
    resultsAK = tk.Label(GUI, text = "Total Pay: $" + "%.2f" % salaryAK).grid(row=5, column=1)
def AKTax():
    global hoursWorked, payRate
    return (float(hoursWorked.get()) * float(payRate.get())) - (float(payRate.get()) * AK)
AK2.trace("w", AZTax)

#TAXES
AL = 0.035
AZ = 0.03565
AK = 1
AR = 0.039
CA = 0.0715
CO = 1
CT = 0.04995
DE = 0.044
FL = 1
GA = 0.035
HI = 0.04825
ID = 4.5
IL = 1
IN = 1
IA = 0.0467
KS = 0.0405
KY = 0.04
LA = 0.04
ME = 0.06475
MD = 0.03875
MA = 1
MI = 1
MN = 0.076
MS = 0.04
MO = 0.0375
MT = 0.0395
NE = 0.0465
NV = 1
NH = 1
NJ = 0.05185
NM = 0.033
NY = 0.0641
NC = 1
ND = 0.02
OH = 0.0275
OK = 0.0275
OR = 0.0745
PA = 1
RI = 0.0487
SC = 0.035
SD = 1
TN = 1
TX = 1
UT = 1
VT = 0.0625
VA = 0.03875
WA = 1
WV = 0.0475
WI = 0.05825
WY = 1
DC = 0.06475

#ENTRY
tk.Label(GUI, text='Pay Rate:', font="110").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(GUI, text='Hours Worked:', font="110").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(GUI, textvariable = payRate)
e2 = tk.Entry(GUI, textvariable = hoursWorked)
e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.W)
e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.W)

#OPTION MENU
opt = tk.StringVar()
opt.set("Choose a state")

option = tk.OptionMenu(GUI, opt, *States).grid(row=2, column=0)

frame = tk.Frame(GUI)
frame.grid()

button = tk.Button(frame, text='Calculate', fg='red', command=calculateAL, calculateAK, calculateAZ)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

#SET DEFAULTS
hoursWorked.set(0)
payRate.set(0)

#EVENT LOOP
GUI.mainloop()
````

Comment: using `command=calculateAL, calculateAK, calculateAZ` to run three functions will not work. Create one function which runs `calculateAL()` `calculateAK()` `calculateAZ()` and then use this function whith `command=`

Comment: in `OptionMenu` you use `opt` and there you have selected option - so use `opt.get()` in functions which you run by pressing button.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
#init root
root1 = tk.Tk()
#set location
fields = ['some input variable','some option variable']
for field in fields:
    row = tk.Frame(root1)
    lab = tk.Label(row, width=33,text=field+': ',anchor='w')
    if field == 'some input ':
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0,'ANY DEFAULT VALUE')
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,expand=tk.YES,fill=tk.X)
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        continue
    elif field == 'some option variable':
        #spec options
        options = ['ALL'] + ['a'] + .....
        variable = tk.StringVar(root1)
        ent = tk.OptionMenu(row,variable,*options)
        #unpack the setting.
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,expand=tk.YES,fill=tk.X)
root1.mainloop()
```